# get request fail angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2, get-request

I create network services that should send get request with 1 param,
and I should get the result from the API,

NetworkServices.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class NetworkServices{
  constructor(public http:Http){

  }
  getCurrency(obj){
    console.log("function fired!")
    let url = 'http://api.fixer.io/latest?base='+obj.selectedCurrency;
    console.log(obj);
    this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then( (res) => {
          return res;
        }
      )
  }
}
```

the results should be at res, this was work 3 weeks ago, I dont know how angular manage to change heh..

the error code is:

```
[19:46:04]  transpile update started ...
[19:46:06]  typescript: D:/ionic/firstApp/src/services/network.ts, line: 25 
            Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.

      L24:    return this.http.get(url).toPromise();
[19:46:06]  transpile update failed       L25:
}

[19:46:06]  watch ready
```

hope you guys can solve this :)

Comment: What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior?

Comment: Do you even get something in res??? check with API `url` whether it hits the correct api or not..

Comment: add a .catch() too, to display the error if there is one.

Comment: hey guys i just update the question i added it the error.
@GünterZöchbauer;
@Gnujeremie;
@micronyks;

Comment: You have to import `toPromise`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method doesn't return anything, and the then callback doesn't do anything other than transforming a `Promise<Response>` into another `Promise<Response>`. So your whole method is basically a noop.

The code should probably look like

```
getCurrency(obj){
    console.log("function fired!")
    let url = `http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=${obj.selectedCurrency}`;
    console.log(obj);
    return this.http.get(url).toPromise();
}
```

Or, if you want to return a promise containing the json body of the response rather than the response itself

```
getCurrency(obj){
    console.log("function fired!")
    let url = `http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=${obj.selectedCurrency}`;
    console.log(obj);
    return this.http.get(url).toPromise().then(res => res.json());
}
```

Regarding your compilation error, you need to import the toPromise operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

Comment: Hey, i tried both if your code and both of them give me the same error code I update it in the question.
@JB Nizet

Comment: I amended my answer.